# how to copy a .db file from assets to FileSystem in expo

Tags: expo

1. Expo SDK Version: 36.0.0
2. Platform: iOS Simulator

I need to copy a `.db` file from assets to the `FileSystem.documentDirectory` but I get an error. Here's the code I'm trying:

```
    await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
        Asset.fromModule(require('../assets/databases/data.db')).uri,
        `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/data.db`
    );
```

Here's the error I get:

```
Unable to resolve module "../assets/databases/data.db"
None of these files exist:
* assets/databases/data.db(.native|.ios.expo.ts|.native.expo.tx|.expo.ts|.ios.expo.tsx|.native.expo.tsx|.expo.tsx|.ios.expo.js|.native.expo.js|.expo.js|.ios.expo.jsx|.native.expo.jsx|.expo.jsx|.ios.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.ios.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx|.ios.js|.native.js|.js|.ios.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.ios.json|.native.json|.json|.ios.wasm|.native.wasm|.wasm)
```

How do i copy a `.db` file from assets to the `FileSystem.documentDirectory` folder?  I just need to copy a `.db` file from assets to the `FileSystem.documentDirectory` folder, but this error makes it look like `Asset.fromModule` only allows image files.

If I use the *exact* same code but replace the `.db` file with a `.png` file, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer from a combination of expo forum posts, primarily this one: https://forums.expo.io/t/unable-to-load-obj-file-using-require/15794/3

The problem is that by default, the expo `Assets` api doesn't recognize `.db` files, so you have to create a file in the root of your project called `metro.config.js` and then add the following code to the file:

```
module.exports = {
    resolver: {
        assetExts: ["db", "ttf", "png"]
    }
};
```

After that, you can then do this and it will work:

```
    await FileSystem.downloadAsync(
        Asset.fromModule(require('../assets/databases/data.db')).uri,
        `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/data.db`
    );
```

Comment: for me only ```await FileSystem.copyAsync({ from: initialDatabaseAsset.uri, to: `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/data.db` });``` was working. ``downloadAsync`` didn't like the absolute path on the native app. Expo Go and Simulator Builds were working fine. As the asset file were already bundled with the app I could use copy. You can check this by renaming your ipa file to zip and unpacking it. I think on android it should work similar.

Answer (score 0):

1. Expo SDK Version: 36.0.0
2. Platform: android expo client sdk-qr code

i am also need this db file and i dont understand how to get it ..

my code here just give me the path ..but no have path like that , i just want to see my db file and i want to save this file in my desktop . how can i do that ?

```
const { uri } = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(
        `${FileSystem.documentDirectory}SQLite/${'places.db'}`
    )
     console.log("THIS IS PATH OF THE DB",uri)
```

Comment: see my answer above to fix this issue.